# Partial Match of a string for each row of a data frame

Tags: r

Using iris data as an example to illustrate my question, I would like to do a partial match on say ".5" and get the index of the position (In my real data 0.5 is actually a string "_mutations").

I intend to loop through each row, perform the partial match, get the index of the first match. I have used the following;

```
idx = regexpr(pattern, txt[i,], ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)[1]

idx = regexec(pattern, txt[i,], ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)[1]

gregexpr(pattern, txt[j,], ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
          fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)

stri_locate_first_regex(txt[i,], pattern)

str_detect(txt[i,], pattern)
```

Example data is as given below;

```
library(ggplot2)
txt = iris
pattern=".5"
```

Expected result is the index of the first match.

Answer (score 2):

Replace all values with `TRUE` for the match

```
df <- iris
# [] notation preserves structure
df[] <- lapply(X = df, function(x) {
    grepl(pattern = ".5",
          x = as.character(x),
          fixed = TRUE)
})
```

Get the location of `TRUE` values for each column

```
sapply(X = df, which)
```

## Results

```
# $Sepal.Length
# [1]  34  37  42  54  55  81  82  90  91 105 111 117 148
# 
# $Sepal.Width
# [1]   1  18  28  37  41  44  70  73  90  99 107 109 114 147
# 
# $Petal.Length
# [1]   4   8  10  11  16  20  22  28  32  33  35  40  49  52  56  61  67  69  79  80
# [21]  85  86 107 113 117 138
# 
# $Petal.Width
# [1]  24  52  53  55  62  67  69  73  79  85  87 101 110 120 134 145
# 
# $Species
# integer(0)
```

## Notes

There is a number of ways this can be solved. I like this solution as the results are quite readable but I reckon that to a great extent it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Great answer! If OP wants something they can subset with, another options is to use the results of the `lapply` statement w/ `pmax` (i.e., `do.call(pmax, results_from_lapply)`)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `which` in combination with `grepl` ?

```
which(grepl("0.5", iris$Petal.Width))[1]
```

**EDIT**

Following your comment, here is another attempt that provide a vector of all row index with a partial match.

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  mutate(row_index = as.numeric(rownames(.))) %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(grepl("0.5", .))) %>%
  pull()
```

Not sure it is the easiest way to do it though.

Comment: actually I am looking for any ".5" partial match across all columns in each row

Answer (score 0):

Does the following produce your desired output?

```
grep(pattern, txt[i,])[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rapply` to search each cell for your pattern using `grepl`, and replace the cell value with `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Then use `rowSums` to add up all the `TRUE`(1) and `FALSE`(0) cells by row, and see if there is at least one match `>= 1`.

```
rowSums(rapply(iris, function(x) grepl(pattern = ".5", x, fixed = T), how = "replace")) >= 1
```

Here, I am assuming you wanted the `.` to match a period and not any character (which is what it will match in a regular expression if it is not escaped (i.e., `\\.`), or if `fixed = TRUE`. Also, note, that if you are searching for `"_mutations"` on a larger dataset, that `fixed = TRUE` will be a quicker:

And, using it to subset:

```
idx <- rowSums(rapply(iris, function(x) grepl(pattern = ".5", x, fixed = T), how = "replace")) >= 1
head(iris[idx, ])

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
16          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
```